# Cannot access the <nz-options> element (ngzorro directive) angular testing(jasmine and karma)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

What I want to achieve is to access the nz-options which I am trying to do by accessing its class and shows that the ngFor has not been triggered. Is there any fix?

The error I am getting is that "Error: Expected 0 to be greater than 0."
html file

```
<nz-select nzShowSearch style="width: 100%" formControlName="basic" (ngModelChange)="basicChanged()">
                        <nz-option class="nzOptions" *ngFor="let item of example" 
                            [nzLabel]="item.productMarketingName"
                            [nzValue]="item.productId">
                        </nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NgZorroAntdModule } from 'app/ng-zorro.module';
import { SubmissionDataComponent } from './submission-data.component';


describe('SubmissionDataComponent', () => {
    let component: SubmissionDataComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubmissionDataComponent>;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SubmissionDataComponent],
            providers: [],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, 
              FormsModule,TranslateModule.forRoot(),NgZorroAntdModule,BrowserAnimationsModule]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubmissionDataComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
      it('Should check if dropdown has data', () => { <--- Test case
        component.example=[
            {"productMarketingName":'test1'},
            {"productMarketingName":'test2'},
            {"productMarketingName":'test3'},
        ]
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const element = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.nzOptions'));
        expect(element.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
        
    })
});
```

Comment: After the `fixture.detectChanges();`, you can `console.log(fixture.nativeElement);` to see what the DOM has at that point in time. I bet `nz-option` is not painted then, probably hidden by an `*ngIf`.

Comment: You are right again. I can only see nz-select and no nz-option inside it but I dont see a *ngIf on the nz-options, It is just like what I have provided on the example above. can it be else where?

Comment: Maybe you're missing a module in the `imports` array for it to be painted.